# Find missing number in sequence in string

Tags: algorithms, strings, numbers, string-matching, sequence

I have a string that contains numbers in sequence. There are no delimiters between numbers. I have to find missing number in that sequence. For example:

```
176517661768 is missing the number: 1767
8632456863245786324598632460 is missing the number: 8632458
```

I have no idea how to even start. As you can see, I don't know the number length either. On top of that, I am mostly a C programmer so get little help from inbuilt functions. Nevertheless I am looking for a good algorithm that I can implement myself. However, code/pseudo-code is highly appreciated.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: Is it possible for the sequence to change the number of digits over the course of the string?  `99101` or `98100` being examples of this.

Comment: Woah! So many downvotes! Somebody care to point out what's wrong with the question? I am new.

Comment: @Neo the combination of not trying anything initially and asking for code or pseudocode.  Yes, you don't know where to start but thinking through a problem is a key part to figuring out how to solve it. What if you were given this as a string of tiles with numbers written on them - how do you (as a person) identify the sequence?

Comment: Autocorrelation of the sequence, will reveal the cycle length of the substring. And then you will know that the first string has a cycle length of 4 and for the second string has 7. You might find out the next steps to do then.

Comment: @thepacker this may have difficulty with a sequence such as `979899101102`

Comment: @MichaelT, indeed this is one of the cornercases, But i think the Autocorrelation will have a different "look" for that. But i agree, my solution isn't perfect, but another way to think about the problem - what is even more desired, if someone wants to find a "good algorithm that" he can implement.

Comment: @thepacker you might want to try your hand at [Find the missing number in an undelimited string](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73305/12166) noting that `911` is one of the test cases.

Comment: @MichaelT Thank you for the pointer, but i am currently in different topics (DSL, Codegeneration etc.) - Nice idea to turn that into a codegolf - but I must admit I won't participate.

Comment: Will there be only *one* missing number sequentially? Will there be only *one* missing number in each string?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is entirely one of forming a hypothesis and testing it.

So, we have `176517661768`.  Ok.  The first hypothesis is that the first number is one digit long. That would be a `1`.  This would mean that I expect the next number to be either a `2` or `3` (if the hole is a `2`).  Lets check that out.

- `1` - got it.
- `7` - not a 2 or a 3.

Ok, lets throw that out.

The second hypothesis is that the first number is two digits long.  That would be a `17`.  This would mean that I expect the number to be `18` or `19`.

- `17` - got it
- `65` - not 18 or 19.

Lets try this again.  It might be *three* digits long.  That would mean `176`.

- `176` - got it
- `517` - not a 177 or 178.

Lets try this yet again.  It might be ***four*** digits long.

- `1765` - got it
- `1766` - still matching with the hypothesis
- `1768` - still matching with the hypothesis (and we have a hole, set that aside)..
- ...

Figuring out how to do the appropriate substrings or stream processing is left as an exercise to the reader for their chosen language.  This will likely fall into the approach where you are writing a type of state machine where you are only going forward and testing for two possible conditions - the next value or the next value plus one (and once you find a situation where you've accepted next value plus one, all future states have only one acceptance test - that of next value).